# Active: Activating (start-post) | Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-ec2

I have been facing the following issue for MYSQL.

```
Active: activating (start-post) since Thu 2023-06-08 10:00:07 UTC; 7s ago
```

It happens at start of server, I tried restarting/start mysql and server but didn't work, also could not find any suggestion across the internet to solve the issue for my case.

Following is the screen shot to check the complete details of the problem.

[image]

Appreciate your help in advance.